# In R, converted factor variables to numeric don't show as such and recoding Likert scale doesn't work. Why is this?

Tags: r, numeric, data-conversion

So I have used this function to convert from factor to numeric in R:

```
Project_dataset$Q3_2NUM<-as.numeric(Project_dataset$Q3_2)
Project_dataset$Q3_3NUM<-as.numeric(Project_dataset$Q3_3)
Project_dataset$Q3_4NUM<-as.numeric(Project_dataset$Q3_4)
```

I also checked it this way:

```
class(Project_dataset$Q3_1NUM)
class(Project_dataset$Q3_2NUM)
class(Project_dataset$Q3_3NUM)
class(Project_dataset$Q3_4NUM)
```

And it confirms that it has indeed changed to 'numeric' value. However, when I double check with this function:

```
Project_dataset$Q3_1NUM==Project_dataset$Q3_1
Project_dataset$Q3_2NUM==Project_dataset$Q3_2
Project_dataset$Q3__3NUM==Project_dataset$Q3_3
Project_dataset$Q3__4NUM==Project_dataset$Q3_4
```

It gives an output that's `"FALSE"`. I also don't see a change in my dataset from factor to numeric values.

ALSO, I am trying to recode Likert Scales in my dataset so that I can run chi-square test, spearman correlation, as well as logistical regression accurately. By recoding, this is what I mean: this is my Likert scale range for one of the variables:

1= Never, 2=less than once a month, 3=once a month, 4=2-3 times a month, 5=once a week, 6=2-3 times a week, 7=daily, 8=multiple times per day)

I am attempting to combine 2,3,and 4 so 2=0-3 times a month. I am also wanting to combine 5,6,and 7 so 3=1-3 times a week.

So far, I've tried different versions of this:

```
Project_dataset$Q8_2<-recode(Project_dataset$Q8_2, "(2)Less than once a month:(4)2-3 times a month = (2) 0-3 times a month")
```

But it hasn't worked. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

What do I do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you show few values of the `dput(head(Project_dataset$Q8_2))` with `dput` so that I can test it.  Also, what is your expected output for that input.

Comment: `recode` needs a key/value pair.  If you check the documentation `char_vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE);
recode(char_vec, a = "Apple")`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for? You want me to run the function you put in your comment or...? I apologize. I'm a beginner at R...

Comment: What I meant is that your `recode` command is only showing key and not value ie. it is a single string.  If you check the example i posted as comment above, it is different and without any examples, I cannot test your case

Comment: Okay, so.. I'm trying to combine likert scales in a variable. The range of this likert scale is 8 options (I listed them above in my initial question). I also listed how I want to combine it. In the end, I want to reduce the likert scale to a scale of 4 options instead of 8. Does that make sense? I'm not sure if I answered what you were asking. I feel as if everything is going over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the columns of interest in the dataset with `lapply` and apply the columns of the dataset (which is a `vector`) to `numeric`.  It is possible that the columns are `factor`.  In that case, we convert it to `character` first and then to `numeric`

```
nm1 <- paste0("Q3_", 1:4)
nm2 <- paste0(nm1, "NUM") 
Project_dataset[nm2] <- lapply(Project_dataset[nm1], 
          function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

---

Or if the columns have only numeric values, then use `type.convert`

```
Project_dataset <- type.convert(Project_dataset, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: it did work! Could you help with the 2nd part of the edited questions if you can? Thanks!

Comment: @Sully Can you please post as a new question thanks

Comment: It won't let me till 90 minutes later. I'm not sure if this is because I just joined...but I really do need help

Comment: Also, for the function you shared earlier: Project_dataset<-lapply(Project_dataset,as.numeric). It worked but it changed my dataset to a pre-summary format if that makes sense. Like vectors instead of numeric values? Because when I double check that, it says "logistic" instead of "numeric". Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: @Sully That was my previous comment because I thought your column types were `character`.  But, then I realized, it may be `factor` instead of `character`.  So, it is changed to `lapply(Project_dataset[nm1], 
          function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`.  Note that if you direcly convert `factor` to numeric, `as.integer(factor(c('a', 'b', 'a'))`, it will get the integer storage values and not hte actual values

Comment: @Sully I have to leave now